# GoAccess 0.8 on Centos 5.6 64b

Tags: centos, goaccess

I just installed GoAccess 0.8 on Centos 5.6 64b, when I run the command goaccess -f / var/log/apache2/access.log -a, out the window FORMAT LOG CONFIGURATION, but if I select any format comes out error:

An error has ocurred Error ocurred at: parser.c - parse_log - 1059 Messagge: No such file or directiory

How should I proceed? I'm not a linux expert.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It appears that GoAccess is unable to load your log file. Make sure `/var/log/apache2/access.log` exists and you have permissions to read it.

Also, in CentOS, by default the log is recorded in `/var/log/httpd/access_log` instead of `/var/log/apache2/access.log`.